# Running and accessing multiple instances of JBoss

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss, mod-jk

I have 5 instances of JBoss configured and running on different ports (8080 to 8480),and each instance is assigned for a particular project team.I would like to configure it further so that users belonging to a project should be able to access their instance (node) just by typing the URL/node without mentioning the port number, like for example, http://localhost/node1 should take them to the first instance and so on.
I understand that mod_jk can be used to achieve this on a server with a single node.Would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out here.

Thanks,
Nagaraj

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use `mod_jk`, just use a `mod_proxy` to do the work. just place this in your apache configuration:

```
<Location /node1>
   ProxyPass http://<jboss_server_name>:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse http://<jboss_server_name>:8080/
</Location>

<Location /node2>
   ProxyPass http://<jboss_server_name>:8180/
   ProxyPassReverse http://<jboss_server_name>:8180/
</Location>

...
```

this way all request to `/node1` will be forwarded to your first jboss instance, and `/node2` will be forwarded to your second jboss instance, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I have tested it, and it seems to work, though there are a few problems with page rendering and links.Below are the additional things that I have configured apart from the ones you suggested:

        ProxyHTMLURLMap / /node1/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap /node1 /node1
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLExtended On
        SetOutputFilter  proxy-html
        
Since the setup will be used by testers for the live testing of newly developed java codes,I am hesitant to use this method.Would welcome any other suggestions if any.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to meet my requirement using mod_jk, by following this excellent article at

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8561.

Though written for apache/tomcat,it provided enough info for me to get going, and apply it successfully in my environment.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't like the fact that the article makes it easy by skipping the Apache load balancer config by using non-balanced domain names.  too easy, and not the best way of doing it.